# Можно ли подключить винт с SATA-II к материнской плате с SATA-III

Tags: железо

Можно ли подключить накопитель с интерфейсом SATA-II к материнской плате с SATA-III?

Comment: Да. (текст, потому что ограничения so).

Answer (score 1):

Можно, но работать будет как SATA II

Comment: Спасибо вам.Надеюсь, не подвдёт